# Did the PIE word for "copper" mean "imitation"?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Michiel de Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary of Latin* has for PIE:

***a̯ei̯os*** *copper*

and

***a̯eimos*** *imitation, substitute*

***a̯imea̯*** *image, copy*

All three words seemingly have the same root a̯ei̯-

Are these two words related? Did the word for copper initially mean "fake gold"?

Comment: Fake gold even today is often made from mostly copper.

Comment: Where are you getting the latter two words? It's generally good practice to link to a source when you cite PIE reconstructions, since authorities don't all agree on forms or meanings.

Comment: @Tom Recht it is from Lubotsky's etymological dictionary of Latin language.

Comment: @Anixx, never heard of this dictionary before. Surely, you meant to say de Vaan 2008? Alexander Lubotsky is the series editor. http://iedo.brillonline.nl/dictionaries/content/latin/index.html

Comment: @Alex B. yes...

Answer (score 7):

Copper being one of the earliest metals known to humans (it's the main component of bronze), I should rather think that *if* they are indeed related, there must be a simpler link related to smithery — and, by extension, artifice. We still talk of *forgeries*.